# Why is an unboxed struct rvalue in c#

Tags: c#, .net, struct

Let's look at the following code.

```
struct SPoint
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public SPoint(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

class Test
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        SPoint s = new SPoint(3, 4);
        object o = s;
        ((SPoint) o).x = 5;
    }
}
```

Why isn't the last assignment possible? What is the reason for such behaviour?

Comment: Side note: Your struct is mutable.  Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `s` is a `struct` (a.k.a: a [value type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx)), ***`(SPoint)o` is a copy of the data***:

From the C# language spec (§1.3, "Types and Variables"):

> When a value of a value type is converted to type object, an object instance, also called a “box,” is allocated to hold the value, and the value is copied into that box. Conversely, when an object reference is cast to a value type, a check is made that the referenced object is a box of the correct value type, and, if the check succeeds, the value in the box is copied out.

***The language protects you*** from changing the data ***of the cloned value type*** without putting it in a variable first, since you might think that you are changing the original `s.x` value while you are changing it's temporary (not - variabled) clone, unlike unsafe languages like C++/CLI where this kind of assignments might be allowed.

If you want, you are able to explicitly create a new variable and do your manipulations in it:

```
SPoint cloneOfS = ((SPoint)o);
cloneOfS.x = 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1zd0a13x.aspx):

> The result of an unboxing conversion is a temporary variable. The compiler prevents you from modifying such variables because any modification would go away when the temporary variable goes away. To fix this, declare a new value-type variable to store the intermediate expression, and assign the result of the unboxing conversion to that variable.